# InternalError(1267, "Illegal mix of collations (greek_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'")

Tags: html, mysql, input, utf-8, collation

I know this topic has been fully answered, but my problem is sort of different. I have set as utf8 default charset both in the connection I make to mysqldb in my python code and my html files.

```
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='myhost', port=3306, user='user1',passwd='******', db='mydb', charset='utf8')
```

The problem kept on coming up though, so I had to check if my db records are all on the same encoding, and they are all on utf8.
The problem appears when I insert greek input in my html search form, but if press the submit button of the form with blank input it displays greek records just fine. I have also used every accept charset `<head>` and `<meta>` available on my html files.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8">
    </form>
    </meta>
```

Is there any other way I can make sure the form input is on utf8? I am very new to databases so I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Your tables should also be set to UTF8 in the phpMySql

Comment: What does the `</meta>` do in your source?

Comment: Could you show us the SQL statement that is causing the problem?  The `<form>` is out of the picture.

Comment: Can you write Python code to dump the text in question?

Answer (score 0):

In `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`), `ΑΒΓΔ` is hex `CE91 CE92 CE93 CE94`.  In `CHARACTER SET greek`, it is hex `C1 C2 C3 C4`.

Dump the text from Python to see what you get.  Dump the MySQL table to see what is stored:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...
```

Note that in `greek`, each letter is one byte; in `utf8`, each letter is two bytes, like 'CExx'.

```
for i, c in enumerate(u):
    print i, '%04x' % ord(c), unicodedata.category(c),
    print unicodedata.name(c)
```

In Python source, the 1st or 2nd line in source code (to have literals in the code utf8-encoded):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

[*More random python notes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python).